# Pigeon Hole Principle with 13 birds somewhere

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

$13$ birds are landing somewhere. Destiny wants that each of the $5$ birds that you choose $4$ of them must stand on a circle. Prove that there at least $6$ birds on the same circle.

I don't know how use the property of the circle in the proof. But I tried something else which is to use the pigeon hole directly but that didn't help.

Can somebody give an explanation on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: No, it is not a proof : I don't understand the uprising of your 10/5. Besides, I am puzzled by the fact that it is circles ; I am not sure that a supplementary property of circles is hidden behind that ...

Comment: Well I didn't take that into account because I'm not sure how. I tried to use remainder in of 13 divided by 5.

Comment: Maybe the surface of the circle might come in handy.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea.

Comment: I know I didn't show much effort but I don't have a clue on how to apply a circle's property other than the perimeter and surface of a circle.

Comment: Hint: fix four non-concyclic birds and do stuff. What if such four birds don't exist? Also, remember that the circle through 3 fixed points is unique. Forget about area and perimeter.

Comment: So you have four circles who don't have the same center but may cross eachother. If such birds don't exist I think they could not be in the same circle.

Comment: @cip999 I don't get your hint I'm afraid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us consider, among all birds, $4$ that are not on the same circle. Let us call these birds $A, B, C, D\,\,$.  Within this group, we can identify $4$ possible subsets  of $3$ birds ($ABC\,\,$,  $ABD\,\,$, $ACD\,\,$, $BCD\,\,$). Each  of these subsets identifies a unique circle. Let us trace these $4$ circles.

Now let us consider the groups of $5$ birds that can be obtained by taking $A,B,C,D\,\,$ plus a fifth bird given by any of the remaining $13-4=9\,\ $ ones. In each of these $9$ groups, the fifth bird must necessarily stand on one of the above mentioned  $4$ circles.

So we have to place $9$ birds on $4$ circles that already contain $3$ birds each. Even if we homogeneously distribute the first $8$ of these birds among the $4$ circles (i.e. $2$ birds for each circle), we are left with $4$ circles containing $5$ birds each, and one last bird to be placed on one of these. Thus, there must necessarily be a circle that contains at least $6$ birds.